# How to parse number bytes/sec from the following data?

Tags: python, rsync

I am using rsync command to get the file information:

```
info = subprocess.Popen(['sshpass', '-p', password, 'rsync', '-az', '--status', '--dry-run', source],
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

I am getting output like this:

```
drwxr-xr-x          4,096 2013/01/23 08:48:35 my_files
-rw-r--r--      5,009,545 2013/01/16 04:20:48 my_files/NC_008253.fna
-rw-r--r--      5,009,545 2013/01/16 04:20:52 my_files/ok.txt
-rw-r--r--      5,009,545 2013/01/16 04:21:08 my_files/test.data

Number of files: 4 (reg: 3, dir: 1)
Number of created files: 0
Number of deleted files: 0
Number of regular files transferred: 0
Total file size: 15,028,635 bytes
Total transferred file size: 0 bytes
Literal data: 0 bytes
Matched data: 0 bytes
File list size: 135
File list generation time: 0.001 seconds
File list transfer time: 0.000 seconds
Total bytes sent: 25
Total bytes received: 147

sent 25 bytes  received 147 bytes  11.10 bytes/sec
total size is 15,028,635  speedup is 87,375.78 (DRY RUN)
```

I want to parse the number before `bytes/sec i.e 11.10`. How can I do that? Also, is it the bandwidth speed of server?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you don't want to do regular expressions and if the output from the command is consistent, something as simple as this will work:

```
speed = float(info.split("\n")[-2].split(" ")[-2])
```

Don't know if this is the speed of the server, though.